# Get ActiveCells in ActiveSheet using VSTO

Tags: vsto

I am trying to get the ActiveCells in the ActiveSheets. 
This Code, 
**Excel.Range Target = (Excel.Range)this.ExcelApp.ActiveCell;** 
gives me all the active cells in the current Workbook. But I need the ActiveCells in current Sheet, 
**Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)this.ExcelApp.ActiveSheet;**

Your Hints will be highly value to me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I did not get your question !!!! what actually you want to fetch ?

Comment: I am trying to get all the selected cells in the current worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

try this.....

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet ws=(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)this.ActiveSheet;
Range activeCells=this.Application.ActiveCell;
```

activeCell will contain the range of active cell in sheet u can use activeCell to do any peration....

Comment: Thanks, 
"this.Application.ActiveCell" retrives all the selected cells in the current Active-workbook. But I have to get the all the selected Cells in the current Active-WorkSheet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can unless you activate the Worksheet.